# Me ajude a consumir a API de NLU do IBM Watson

Tags: c#, api, inteligência-artificial, watson

Ontem eu assisti um video de um cara que consumiu a API de Natural Language Understanding do Watson (IBM cloud) com JS usando Node e ele fez coisas bem legais com ela...
Por outro lado eu estou tentando consumir e ver os resultados para fazer alguma coisa, mas nem sei se estou indo pelo caminho certo pois é a primeira fez que faço algo do tipo e pra piorar não tem documentação para C#

To usando o nugget pack [IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.v1/)

```
TokenOptions token = new TokenOptions
            {
                IamApiKey = "Minha ApiKey",
                ServiceUrl = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api"
            };

            var nlu = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingService(token, "2018-12-19");

            var parametros = new Parameters { Text = "I'm Michael Jackson the king of POP"};

            var resultado = nlu.Analyze(parametros);
```

Até o momento o que estou fazendo é colocar um Breaking Point em "Resultado" e ver no que da e o que da não é bom! Resulta no seguinte erro:

> IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.v1.dll: 'One or more errors occurred. (The API query failed with status code BadRequest: Bad Request | x-global-transaction-id: ffea405d5d1cfc0efeae7731 | X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: gateway02-4272846641 | error: {
>     "error": "no features specified",
>     "code": 400
>   })'

Comment: A resposta da API é essa: `"error": "no features specified"`. Você não esqueceu de algo no meio do caminho?

Comment: Acho que não, em "parametros" eu tentei especificar o tipo de feature para pegar só as Keywords, mas ainda assim vinha a mesma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ignorância minha, achei que a resposta fosse um erro quando na verdade eu apenas estava implementando da maneira errada.

A API pede que seja especificado ao menos uma Feature.... Antes de postar a duvida no fórum eu já tinha tentado passar uma feature, mas tinha feito isso de forma errada e por isso o "erro", então pesquisei mais e passei a feature da maneira correta, funcionou e ficou dessa forma:

```
TokenOptions token = new TokenOptions
        {
            IamApiKey = "Minha ApiKey",
            ServiceUrl = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api",
        };

        var nlu = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingService(token, "2018-12-19");

        Features features = new Features();
        features.Keywords = new KeywordsOptions();

        var parametros = new Parameters { Text = "I'm Michael Jackson", Features = features };

        var resultado = nlu.Analyze(parametros).ResponseJson;

        Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```